# Reading csv files to create dataframe

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to read a csv file to create a dataframe (https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html)

Using:

```
spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6
spark-csv_2.11-1.1.0
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
object test {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test")
       val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
       val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
       val df = sqlContext.csvFile("filename.csv")
       ...
 }
}
```

Error:

```
value csvFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
```

I was trying to do as advised here: [Spark - load CSV file as DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704333/how-to-read-csv-file-as-dataframe)

But sqlContext doesn't seem to recognize the csvFile method of CsvContext class.

Any advise would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to look into this project 
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: otherwise you can convert it manually, mentioned https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing some issues with CSV(without Spark-CSV) but here is somethings that you can look at and check if they are OK.

1. Build the Spark shell with the spark-csv library using sbt assembly.
2. Add the spark-csv dependency to POM.XML of you maven project.
3. use the load/save methods of Dataframe API.

[SPARK-CSV GITHUB](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

refer the spark-csv github readme.md page and you will up and running :)

Comment: **1&2.** I already have **"com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.11" % "1.1.0"** in my sbt and when compiling it does not complain about missing dependencies.

**3.** How will the load/save methods help me read the csv?

As for readme.md page, I have already read that, it advises to use sqlContext.load which compiles but at runtime results in "filename.csv" is not a Parquet file. That is why I had followed the advice from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704333/how-to-read-csv-file-as-dataframe

Comment: If you want to to save CSV as parquet then use the dataframe created     HashMap<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
  options.put("header", "true");
  options.put("path", dataFile);
 DataFrame df = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", options);df.save(<hdfs output>,"parquet");