# Spark DataFrame - Read pipe delimited file using SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Based on [Spark - load CSV file as DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704333/spark-load-csv-file-as-dataframe#)

Is it possible to specify options using SQL to set the delimiter, null character, and quote?

```
val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM csv.`csv/file/path/in/hdfs`")
```

I know it can be done using `spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "|")`, but ideally I wouldn't have to.

**Updated Information**

It seems that I have to pass the path using back-ticks.

When I attempting to pass  `OPTIONS`

```
== SQL ==
SELECT * FROM 
csv.`csv/file/path/in/hdfs` OPTIONS (delimiter , "|" )
-----------------------------------^^^

Error in query:
mismatched input '(' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 
'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 
'NATURAL', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 
'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'ANTI'}
```

Comment: How about `SELECT * FROM csv.csv/file/path/in/hdfs OPTIONS (delimiter , "|" )`

Answer (score 2):

Althoguh not a one line souliton, following might work for you:

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE some_table USING com.databricks.spark.csv OPTIONS (path \"csv/file/path/in/hdfs\", delimeter \"|\")");
val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM some_table");
```

Of course you can skip the second step of loading into dataframe if you want to perform some SQL operation directly on `some_table`.