# Generate Dataframe with various number of columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Imagine a csv as follow :

```
a,b,c,d
1,1,0,0
0,1,1,0
...
```

I want to obtain automatically a DF with 4 columns a,b,c,d.

A manual technique can be :

```
val rdd = sc.textFile(path).map(_.split(","))
val cols = (0 until rdd.first.size).map(_.toString).toArray
val df = rdd.map{ case Array(a, b, c, d) => (a, b, c, d) }.toDF(cols:_*)
```

The problem with this technique is that i have to precise manually the number of columns a,b,c,d which can be problematic with hundreds or more features.

I imagine that it exist a more useful method probably passing by sparkSession but i don't want to have to precise any schema.

Comment: If it solved your problem, consider accepting my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spark can automatically infer the schema for you when reading a data file. If you have a CSV file with headers, you can use

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(path)
```

Given your example, it'll result in (using `df.show()`):

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|  0|  1|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Row` and schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val header = rdd.first

spark.createDataFrame(
  rdd.map(row => Row.fromSeq(row.take(header.size))), 
  StructType(header map (StructField(_, StringType)))
)
```

but here, [just use Spark CSV reader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39533431/9613318).

> but i don't want to have to precise any schema.

There is really nothing you can do about it. `DataFrames` require schema. It can be provided either explicitly as `DataType` or implicitly by reflection and with unknown number of columns, you'd need a lot of metaprogramming magic, to generate required case classes on runtime.

Related:

- [How to convert rdd object to dataframe in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29383578/9613318)
- [Spark - load CSV file as DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29704333/9613318)