# Why does finding the max of numbers in my DataFrame yield 0?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

My below program attempts to print the price of the most expensive house, given a CSV file containing information regarding the houses. Unexpectedly, I receive 0 as the max price instead of a non-zero integer (which I have confirmed the existence of, for example the first entry in the CSV file)?

**Program**

```
public class SparkWordCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("WordCounter").config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate();

        String fileName = SparkWordCounter.class.getResource("/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv").toString();

        StructField[] structFields = {
            DataTypes.createStructField("street", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("city", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("zip", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("state", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("beds", DataTypes.ByteType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("baths", DataTypes.ByteType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("sqFt", DataTypes.ShortType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("type", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("sale_data", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("price", DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("latitude", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("longitude", DataTypes.StringType, false)
        };

        StructType structType = DataTypes.createStructType(structFields);
        Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read().option("header", "true").schema(structType).csv(fileName);

        Dataset<Building> buildingDataset = dataset.as(Encoders.bean(Building.class));

        long price = buildingDataset
                .map(building -> building.price, Encoders.INT())
                .reduce(Integer::max);

        System.out.println("Price: " + price);
    }

    public static class Building implements Serializable {
        public String street;
        public String city;
        public String zip;
        public String state;
        public byte beds;
        public byte baths;
        public short sqFt;
        public String type;
        public String sale_date;
        public int price;
        public String latitude;
        public String longitude;
    }
}
```

**CSV first entry (985 total)**

```
street,city,zip,state,beds,baths,sqFt,type,sale_date,price,latitude,longitude
---,---,---,---,2,1,836,Residential,Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008,59222,38.---,---
```

*`---` represents information revealing location*

The prices are guaranteed to be integers, thus an `int` is used (`byte` and `short` are used for values with smaller ranges).

**Why is 0 being the calculated as the max price?**

Comment: Is that `reduce()` statement correct?

Comment: @Rafael I would think so, something like `Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1).reduce(Integer::max)` gives 4. Though it's entirely possible that Spark's reduce functions differently to the point of changing behavior (one difference is that it doesn't return optional).

Comment: It's correct, just wondering...

Comment: what does `buildingDataset.select("price").show()`. Since you are using spark sql, try leverage SQL functionality?

Answer (score 0):

> Check whether the dataframe loaded from CSV properly or not. You can
>   check the data in it by
>
> ```
> buildingDataset.select("price").show(20)
> ```

If the data for price column data seems fine, then use any one of the way to obtain maximum.

#### SQL API

```
buildingDataset.createOrReplaceTempView("building");
sparkSession.sql("SELECT price FROM building ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1")
  .show();
```

#### Java

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
buildingDataset.orderBy(col("price").desc())
    .limit(1)
    .show();
```

Comment: check this other post, if you face any issue in [reading CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39533431/1592191)

Comment: This solution works, however do you have any insight into why the one I provided does not work? The CSV is loaded correctly (I confirmed that), I'm assuming its because each `Building` instance isn't properly initialized (prices default to 0, default int value).