# Intellij Spark, Scala Read txt file and Select Headers and use it as Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

1. I would like to read a text file directly to dataframe. Not file->rdd->dataframe. Is that possible? I Have read a lot but I cannot make it (read) is not working.
2. While read it I want to select specific headers from it.

Is there any fast solution to this?

Also what imports should I make?

This is my scala file

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf,SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object LoadData {


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Job for Loading Data").setMaster("local[*]") // local[*] will access all core of your machine
val sc = new SparkContext(conf) // Create Spark Context
// Load local file data

val rdd = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/data.txt")
val df = rdd.toDF()


// Read the records

println(rdd.foreach(println))
}
}
```

And my sbt

```
 name := "HelloScala"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.2",
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.2"
)
```

I have the error 
Error:(16, 18) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
    val df = rdd.toDF()

Thank you very much

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far, and provide an [mcve].

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You are very right. I am sorry. I have edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark - load CSV file as DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704333/spark-load-csv-file-as-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is example to read a CSV file (with headers) direct to DataFrame

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DataFrameFromCSVFile {

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit= {

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate()

    val filePath="src/main/resources/data.txt"

    //Chaining multiple options
    val df2 = spark.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","sep"->",","header"->"true")).csv(filePath)
    df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()

  }
}
```

In case if you have a RDD and want to convert to DataFrame

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DataFrameFromRDD {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("Databricks", 20000), ("Spark", 100000), ("Hadoop", 3000)))

    val df = rdd.toDF()

    //TO-DO use df variable
  }
}
```

You are getting toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] val df = rdd.toDF() because, you don't have implicit imports.

As shown on above example use import spark.sqlContext.implicits._ and try rdd.toDF(

Happy coding!!

Thanks

Comment: Thank you a lot!First Example worked like a charm!A little help more, I want to load only specif columns of the file. I use df.select("example") but it is not working. My delimiter is | for my file. How Can I user df.select? Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
val df=spark.read.text("file")
```

what do you mean by specific headers? is this a csv? if so

```
val df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("file.csv")
```

then you can

```
df.select($"header1",$"header2").show() //etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import spark.implicits._ after you set sparkConf(), but you should use SparkSession instead. The following should work

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(""Spark Job for Loading Data").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("data.txt")
```