# How to remove entries that contain empty values in an RDD that contains csv data?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, try-catch

I am trying to map the values from a csv file into an RDD but I get the following error because some of the fields are null.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Following is the code I am using.

```
// Load and parse the data
val data = sc.textFile("data.csv")

val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
```

Is there any way to check if there is a null? I thought of doing it with a try catch method but it doesn't seem to work.

```
val parsedData = data.map(s => {

  try {
    val vector = Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble))
  }catch{
    case e:NumberFormatException => println("Nulls somewhere")
  }
  (vector)
})
```

Comment: spark-csv package can be used to read the csv data. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704333/spark-load-csv-file-as-dataframe. If you want the underlying RDD, call `rdd()` on Dataframe object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out item, that are empty, just add `filter` method into your stream:

```
val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(',').filter(!_.isEmpty).map(_.toDouble))).filter(_.size != 0)
```

This way any empty line will result in empty `Vector`, that can be further filtered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I'm new to scala and not accustomed with the syntax/expressions,can you write the code for how to filter it further?I wanna filter the empty Vector completely from parsedData,since I wanna use it for KMeans algorithm.  Thanks again my friend

Comment: Sure, just add `filter(_.size != 0)`, which means, that only arrays with size at least 1 will get through. I'll edit my answer.