# Rdd to Dataframe where schema is programmatically based on header

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have the following RDD and many just like it:

```
val csv = sc.parallelize(Array(
  "col1, col2, col3",
  "1, cat, dog",
  "2, bird, bee"))
```

I would like to convert the RDD into a dataframe where the schema is created dynamically/programmatically based on the first row of the RDD.

I would like to apply the logic to multiple similar like RDDs and cannot specify the schema programmatically using a case class nor use `spark-csv` to load the data in as a dataframe from the start.

I've created a flattened dataframe, but am wondering how to breakout the respective columns when creating the dataframe?

Current code:

```
val header= file.first()
val data = file.mapPartitionsWithIndex {
  (idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter.drop(1) else iter 
}.toDF(header).show()
```

Current output:

```
+----------------+
|col1, col2, col3|
+----------------+
|     1, cat, dog|
|    2, bird, bee|
+----------------+
```

Comment: If this is from a csv file then read it directly as a dataframe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704333/spark-load-csv-file-as-dataframe

Comment: I cannot read it directly into a dataframe using spark-csv

Comment: How come? Also note that in newer spark version there is no need to use spark-csv as it can be used directly without additional packages, e.g.: `spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("csvfile.csv")`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. There are restrictions in place where I am not able to do so

Answer (score 2):

In most cases it's preferred to read csv files directly as a dataframe, see e.g.: [Spark - load CSV file as DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704333/spark-load-csv-file-as-dataframe).

---

First you need to split the data into arrays, this is true for both the header and the RDD itself:

```
val header = csv.first().split(", ")

val data = full_csv.mapPartitionsWithIndex {
  (idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter.drop(1) else iter 
}.map(_.split(", ")).toDF("arr")
```

Note that the above code will convert the RDD to a dataframe, however, it will only have a single column called `arr`. On the other hand, `header` will be a `Array[String]`.

The next step is to convert the dataframe with a single array column into the correct number of columns and with the correct names (based on `header`):

```
data.select((0 until header.size).map(i => col("arr")(i).alias(header(i))): _*)
```

This will result in the wanted output dataframe:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
|   1| cat| dog|
|   2|bird| bee|
+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}

val csv = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(
    "col1, col2, col3",
    "1, cat, dog",
    "2, bird, bee"))

val header = csv.first.split(",").map(_.trim)

val resultDF = spark.createDataFrame(
    csv.zipWithIndex
    .filter(_._2 > 0)
    .map{case (str, _) => Row.fromSeq(str.split(",").map(_.trim))}
  ,
    StructType(header.map(c => StructField(c, StringType)))
  )

resultDF.show(false)
```

Output :

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |cat |dog |
|2   |bird|bee |
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Note that you need zipWithIndex to filter out the header, mapPartitionsWithIndex will assign an index per partition, not per record.