# Differences in the 2 ways to read CSV into Spark DataFrame?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am becoming familiar with the basics of both Python, Spark, and
PySpark by following [this *Spark By Examples*
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe)
(among others at the same site).  At the very outset, they provide
three ways to read in the same file:

```
spark.read.csv("/tmp/resources/zipcodes.csv")
spark.read.format("csv") \
                  .load("/tmp/resources/zipcodes.csv")
spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.csv") \
                  .load("/tmp/resources/zipcodes.csv")
```

Here, `spark` is an object of class
`pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession`.  The lesson says that the 2nd and
3rd commands are alternatives the the 1st, but for "fully qualified
data source name".  Unfortunately, the doc strings in PySpark are
extremely spartan.  Fully qualified paths are used in all
three examples, however, so the explanation for the `spark.read.format`
commands seems very incomplete.

***What are the differences between the method calls?*** It seems odd
to me that a whole new dedicated `csv` method is needed to deal
specifically with CSV -- unless it is just a wrapper for the `format`
method with CSV-specific conveniences.

**Context:** I am using Spark 3.4.1.  The version was chosen by Anaconda's package manager on Windows 10 based on a Python 3.9 environment.

**What I have found**

One fulsome page I found is [this SaturnCloud
page](https://saturncloud.io/blog/pyspark-performance-differences-between-sparkreadformatcsv-and-sparkreadcsv),
but I'm a puzzled by explanation that the `format` method is more generic and
slower. I can't see that being the case if the `csv` method is a
wrapper -- unless the ingestor is set up in a highly suboptimal fashion
with lots of control flow on a per-record, per-field, or per-character
basis.

The same site also refers to the `csv` method as a "shorthand" for the
`format("csv")`.  This suggests that it doesn't even provide any
additional functionality that a wrapper might, and it shouldn't be any
slower at all.  So the site is self-contradictory.

[This
page](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-CSVFileFormat.html)
refers to the `csv` method as a "shortcut" for `format("csv")`.
Again, this gives a *sense* that it is a thin wrapper, but that is not
consistent with SaturnCloud's indication that there could be
performance differences, nor *Spark By Examples*'s implication that
they are for different forms of the data source name.

The question as to the differences has been posed as a Stack Overflow
[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704333/spark-load-csv-file-as-dataframe#comment88415363_39715436)
before.

Comment: Focus on big items, not small beer as here. Just different ways for same thing. Performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at the source code to uncover this mystery! I'm assuming you're on Spark v3.5.0, the latest at the time of writing this post.

If we have a look at `DataFrameReader.scala`'s [`csv`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L537-L538) method, we see the following:

```scala
@scala.annotation.varargs
def csv(paths: String*): DataFrame = format("csv").load(paths : _*)
```

This shows us that indeed, doing `spark.read.csv()` and doing `spark.read.format("csv").load()` does exactly the same. There should be no difference in performance.

**What about `spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.csv").load()`?**

I had never seen this before, so I decided to try it out in a pyspark shell:

```
>>> df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.csv").load("random_file.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ...
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:587)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:675)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.csv.DefaultSource
    ...
```

This does not work, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

After some digging, I found [this Map](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala#L578-L600) in the source code, which essentially maps the fully qualified data source names to their shorthand (which we've been doing until now). The essential line is this one:

```
"com.databricks.spark.csv" -> csv,
```

So then I tried that in a Spark shell:

```
>>> df1 = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load("random_file.csv")
```

and that worked!!

#### Conclusion

- `spark.read.csv()` and `spark.read.format("csv").load()` do exactly the same thing, the former being a very thin wrapper around the latter
- `org.apache.spark.sql.csv` is not the correct fully qualified data source name for CSV files: it is `com.databricks.spark.csv`

Comment: Thank you, Koedlt.  I think one of my issues was that when I searched the internet for `what-is-a-fully-qualified-data-source-name`, I went down the wrong path and thought that it referred to a full file path.  Instead, I think it is meant to refer to a database connection.  If I am right, then the CSV file is being treated as a database connection.  There's a lot more I have to read up on in order to appreciate the entirety of your answer, but for now, thanks for having cordoned off the one wrong path.

Comment: Things might be different between Python and Scala. I found class
`DataFrameReader` in `pyspark/sql/readwriter.py`, including methods
`format(...)->DataFrameReader`, `load(...)->DataFrame`, and
`csv(...)->DataFrame`.  Method `csv` is not the thin wrapper that
is shown in your answer for Scala.  The are many references go
`self._jreader`, so it's going through an extra layer of interface.
I go the same results with `spark.read.format(...).load(...)` as
you did, including the need to correct the full qualified DSN.
Thanks!

Comment: Nicely found! Actually that `self._jreader` object IS the Scala implementation of `DataFrameReader` I talked about here in this answer, so what I posted here still holds :) Remember that Spark was written in Scala, and pyspark is just a wrapper around the Scala code.

Comment: That's very informative.  Thanks!  I thought the `j` was a mnemonic to indicate some Java layer, but my web wanderings show that Scala is like Java "2.0" for analytics (ignoring the fact that Java proper has evolved through many versions and version numbering conventions well beyond 2.0).