# How to apply map function on in spark java RDD Operations

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

My CSV File:

```
YEAR,UTILITY_ID,UTILITY_NAME,OWNERSHIP,STATE_CODE,AMR_METERING_RESIDENTIAL,AMR_METERING_COMMERCIAL,AMR_METERING_INDUSTRIAL,AMR_METERING_TRANS,AMR_METERING_TOTAL,AMI_METERING_RESIDENTIAL,AMI_METERING_COMMERCIAL,AMI_METERING_INDUSTRIAL,AMI_METERING_TRANS,AMI_METERING_TOTAL,ENERGY_SERVED_RESIDENTIAL,ENERGY_SERVED_COMMERCIAL,ENERGY_SERVED_INDUSTRIAL,ENERGY_SERVED_TRANS,ENERGY_SERVED_TOTAL
2011,34,City of Abbeville - (SC),M,SC,880,14,,,894,,,,,,,,,,
2011,84,A & N Electric Coop,C,MD,135,25,,,160,,,,,,,,,,
2011,84,A & N Electric Coop,C,VA,31893,2107,0,,34000,,,,,,,,,,
2011,97,Adams Electric Coop,C,IL,8334,190,,,8524,,,,,0,,,,,0
2011,108,Adams-Columbia Electric Coop,C,WI,33524,1788,709,,36021,,,,,,,,,,
2011,118,Adams Rural Electric Coop, Inc,C,OH,7457,20,,,7477,,,,,,,,,,
2011,122,Village of Arcade,M,NY,3560,498,100,,4158,,,,,,,,,,
2011,155,Agralite Electric Coop,C,MN,4383,227,315,,4925,,,,,,,,,,
```

Here down the Spark code to read the CSV file:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

public class RddCsv 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CSV Reader").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> allRows = sc.textFile("file:///home/kumar/Desktop/Eletricaldata/file8_2011.csv");//read csv file
    System.out.println(allRows.take(5)); 
   }
}
```

I am new Learner sparkJava,
How to Select Perticuler field value from that  CsvDataset and  How to Perform aggregation Operations, and how to use Transformations and Actions that given Dataset. and how to select perticular field value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Parsing CSV or JSON File with Apache Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362942/how-to-parsing-csv-or-json-file-with-apache-spark)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CSV Reader").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> allRows = sc.textFile("file:///home/abhishek/Desktop/file8_2011.csv");
    System.out.println(allRows.take(5));
    List<String> headers= Arrays.asList(allRows.take(1).get(0).split(","));
    String field="YEAR";
    //Skip Header
    JavaRDD<String>dataWithoutHeaders=allRows.filter(x -> !(x.split(",")[headers.indexOf(field)]).equals(field));
    //Take one field as integer
    JavaRDD<Integer> years=dataWithoutHeaders.map(x -> Integer.valueOf(x.split(",")[headers.indexOf(field)]));
    //Aggregate operation getTotal aggregate() arguments are initial value for a partition,aggregating function for a partition
    //and aggregating function for results from different partition
    int total=years.aggregate(0,RddCsv::sum,RddCsv::sum);
    for (Integer i:years.collect()){
        System.out.println("year :: "+i);
    }
    System.out.println(total);
}

private static int sum(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

This is a basic program.You should read spark's java apis for detailed info.

Comment: not working,compitime errors are comming  this line .aggregate(0,RddCsv::sum,RddCsv::sum);

Comment: I have run it just now.

Comment: output : 16/12/14 16:26:31 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) in 25 ms on localhost (1/1)
16/12/14 16:26:31 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 3.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/12/14 16:26:31 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 3 finished: collect at RDDCsv.java:32, took 0.049729 s
year :: 2011
year :: 2011
year :: 2011
year :: 2011
year :: 2011
year :: 2011
year :: 2011
year :: 2011
16088
16/12/14 16:26:31 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

Comment: Please check your configurations,filenames,etc. or paste your errors in comment.

Comment: this line : int total=years.aggregate(0,RddCsv::sum,RddCsv::sum);List<String> headers= Arrays.asList(allRows.take(1).get(0).split(","));

Comment: I am not asking for line,I am asking error(like build error) because this code is running fine,so it must be due to your project configuration.Please paste error somewhere and put link here.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Arrays cannot be resolved

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Arrays cannot be resolved
 The method aggregate(U, Function2<U,Integer,U>, Function2<U,U,U>) in the type AbstractJavaRDDLike<Integer,JavaRDD<Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (int, RddCsv::sum, RddCsv::sum)
 The type RddCsv does not define sum(U, Integer) that is applicable here
 The type RddCsv does not define sum(U, U) that is applicable here

 at com.inndata.EletricalData.a.main(a.java:17)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130596/discussion-between-abhishek-kumar-and-kumar).

Comment: join me in above chat link.[link]http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130596/discussion-between-abhishek-kumar-and-kumar